# Using a different model if a condition is not satisfied

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, classification

TL;DR: I have two good models, but I want to use one of them only in some cases.

The **first dataframe** looks like this:

```
worker    rated_object    rating
w1        o1              0
w1        o2              0
w1        o3              1
w2        o1              1
w2        o2              1
w2        o4              0
w3        o1              0
w3        o5              1
...
```

To figure out how a `worker` would `rate` an `object`, I created the following **model** and it works well (I rounded the prediction to 0 or 1 and added them to the dataframe):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import surprise
from surprise import KNNWithMeans
from surprise.model_selection import train_test_split
reader = Reader(rating_scale=(0, 1))
data = Dataset.load_from_df(df[['worker', 'rated_object', 'rating']], reader)
trainset, testset = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.20)
algo = KNNWithMeans()
algo.fit(trainset)
test = algo.test(testset)
test = pd.DataFrame(test)
test.drop("details", inplace=True, axis=1)
test.columns = ['worker', 'rated_object', 'actual', 'cf_predictions']

def g(row):
    if row['cf_predictions'] > 0.5:
        val = 1.0
    else:
        val = 0.0
    return val

test['cf_threshold'] = test.apply(g, axis=1)
```

My **second dataframe** is much much smaller and only has info about the `rated_objcts` (and it probably doesn't contain all the objects from the previous dataframe either):

```
rated_object     feature_1    feature_2    feature_n    rating
o1               2.02         0            90.40        0
o2               3.70         1            NaN          1
o3               3.45         0            70.50        1
o4               7.90         1            40.30        0
...
```

To predict the `rating` of an object, I created an **XGBoost model** that works well:

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder 
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
cols_to_drop = ['rated_object'] 
df2.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)
X = df2.drop('rating', axis=1)  
y = df2['rating'] 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=5)
model = XGBClassifier() 
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

However, I want to combine the models. **I want to use the first model when enough workers rated that particular object it (say, a minimum of 3) and the second one otherwise.** If an object isn't found in one of the dataframes, obviously use the other one. I'm thinking something like:

```
def combination(df, df2):
    if num_ratings > 2:
        # incorporate the first model
        return ???cf_predictions???
    else:
        # incorporate the second model
        return ???y_pred???
```

I am not sure what a good output would be, but I want to be able to evaluate its accuracy too. Should the models themselves be written as functons, with a similar type of output? How can I approach this problem?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you intend to pass into `combination()`. Are you going to pass the data frames listed above and then train the model, or are you planning to give it new data and ask it to predict using one of the 2 models based on the length?

Comment: @cazman I am only working with these two dataframes, and I want to see how accurate the new predictions are if, in some cases I use one method, and in other cases the second method. I edited the explanation a bit, I meant to say that I would use the first method only if a minimum of, say, 3 workers rated that particular object.

Comment: @cazman I might as well just create a new model that applies a certain weight to each of these two models. So pred = 0.5 *  model_1 + 0.5 model_2, but I run into the same problem: how do I deal with two different models spitting different outputs from different dataframes?

Comment: Okay, so for a given test set of a single type of rated_object, if the length of the first df is greater than 2, predict with the first model, otherwise, predict df2 using the with the second model?

Comment: @cazman I hope I understand you correctly, yes, so it would be something like `num_ratings = len(df[df['rated_object'] == rated_object])` has to be >2.

Comment: So then given that len(df.index) > 2 is true, can you just call the predict method of the first model on df, otherwise call the predict method of the second model on the second df and return the result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239717/discussion-between-futuredataengineer-and-cazman).